# Why might a hosted web app run faster than on localhost?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, nodejitsu

I've recently written an app using Node/Express/Angular and it's being run on Nodejitsu. I'm also using Mongolab to host the database. The app pretty clearly runs a lot faster when it's "in the cloud" than on my computer going through localhost which is counter-intuitive to me. What are the reasons for this?

Comment: Maybe they have set-ups optimized for serving web-apps? Or maybe your computer just sucks?

Comment: Dude, haven't you seen the commercials? Just say "to the cloud" and your computer grows.

Comment: @WaleedKhan My new 15" MacBook Pro Retina sucks? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a combination of their servers are faster than your local machine, and they have faster network speeds to your database, and the slowest part of your app isn't the network time it takes to send information back and forth to and from your browser, but rather the processing on the server.